# Multiple terms on lucene curl query

Tags: php, curl, lucene, httprequest

I want to do a request to an API using a lucene curl query.

I would match multiple fields, not just one.

For example, this request with just one fields "src_ip" is OK :

'.../query/universal/relative/terms?field=src_ip&query=*&range=86400'

But when I want to match 2 fields (src_ip + dst_ip), I use this request but it doesn't work :

'.../query/universal/relative/terms?field=src_ip%20AND%20dst_ip&query=*&range=86400'

Do you know how to resolve my problem ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is that Lucene expects 'field' string to declare what is being searched for in that field.  If you want '*' perhaps try:

```
.../query/universal/relative/terms?field=src_ip%3A*%20AND%20dst_ip%3A*&range=86400
```

Comment: Possibly remove the range constraint to see if anything is returned?

Comment: I also try that but same problem. It's work fine with just one field (src_ip) but I can't add anoter field :(

Comment: Odd. Specs imply that it's legal construct.  I don't have a Lucene install handy right now, and it's been a while since I've used it directly.  I'll see if I can replicate/verify the correct syntax.